# scp: error: unexpected filename:

Tags: bash, scp

An SCP I've been using for a long time to upload files has suddenly stopped working. I ran the script 12 hours ago and it worked just fine, but has suddenly stopped.

The command in question was uploading the current directory to a remote folder:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd "$(dirname "$0")"

scp -r . <remote_server>:<remote_folder>
```

The error message is:

```
scp: error: unexpected filename: .
```

I'm on a Mac running Mojave 10.14.2.

UPDATE: I have solved the specific problem by rewriting the command to this, but I'd still be interested to know what broke:

```
scp -r $(pwd) <remote_server>:<remote_folder>
```

Comment: I tried on Mojave 10.14.3 and it works. Is the directory empty?

Comment: Please post your answer separately so you get credit for it and other people will find it. I missed seeing it and is why I posted  a near duplicate.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The culprit is [CVE-2018-20685](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2018-20685), whose description is:

> In OpenSSH 7.9, scp.c in the scp client allows remote SSH servers to
>   bypass intended access restrictions via the filename of . or an empty
>   filename. The impact is modifying the permissions of the target
>   directory on the client side.

This is part of a [larger set of SCP vulnerabilities](https://sintonen.fi/advisories/scp-client-multiple-vulnerabilities.txt). Quoting from there:

> ### Overview
>
> SCP clients from multiple vendors are susceptible to a malicious scp
>   server performing unauthorized changes to target directory and/or
>   client output manipulation.
>
> ### Description
>
> Many scp clients fail to verify if the objects returned by the scp
>   server match those it asked for. This issue dates back to 1983 and
>   rcp, on which scp is based. A separate flaw in the client allows the
>   target directory attributes to be changed arbitrarily. Finally, two
>   vulnerabilities in clients may allow server to spoof the client
>   output.

The [commit](https://github.com/openbsd/src/commit/4667d15cf6214d4cb6b8c347f13864ca8c72002e) that patched this vulnerability in OpenBSD was made on Nov. 16, 2018

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So my SCP somehow got updated over night to include this patch is why it stopped working?

Comment: Making the scp tool unable to process the standard directory entry "." is an AWFUL solution to this! There must be 10's of other ways they could have solved this (perhaps by verifying that the returned objects ARE what was asked for?)... This is "security by the least effort expended", which is next in line after "security by not publishing the hostname"...

Comment: Great answer, now I know why my scp scripts on Ubuntu no longer work.  But what is the solution?  I cannot use `*` instead of `.` because the folder contains thousands of files.  Is there a new switch to turn off this behaviour?

Comment: @Stéphane use `$(pwd)` instead of `.`

Comment: @BlackBear It's not the same. `.` allow to copy all files (including those starting with a dot) without copying directory itself. `scp -r $(pwd) <host>:<dest. dir>` and `scp -r . <host>:<dest. dir>` ARE different. In first case you've got `<dest. dir>/<current dir name>/<files list>` when you've got `<dest. dir>/<files list>` with second case.

Comment: @Bill your command can be replaced by tar c . | ssh -C <host> tar x -C <dest. dir>

Comment: @Bill is there any correct way to replace ```scp -r .```?

Comment: @Stéphane why not `*` - am I understanding correctly you want to avoid copying those files? I wanted just to copy all content of directory (not including the directory itself), say `data` and while `scp -r data/.` stopped working, `scp -r data/*` works fine.

Comment: @TomášZáluský Because `*` does not work when the folder contains thousands of filenames.

Answer (score 14):

The other answer from @BlackBear explains **why** this no longer works.

But if like me you ended up on this question also looking for a solution, it seems the right way to do it is with `rsync` instead of `scp`.  For example, one of my old `scp` commands would have looked like this:

```
# this no longer works due to the "."
scp -BCr output/html/. www:/var/www/site/html/
```

Now instead I use this:

```
rsync --recursive --times --compress --delete --progress output/html/ www:/var/www/site/html/
```

If you prefer the shorter flags, it would look like this:

```
rsync -rtz --del --progress output/html/ www:/var/www/site/html/
```

The trailing `/` on the source is important.  It tells rsync you want the **content** of that directory without the directory name.

Also consider `--dry-run` and `man rsync` before messing things up.

Comment: This solution doesn't work for Windows. On Windows only the scp command exists but the rsync doesn't.

Comment: @besnep If you don't have it, you'll have to install it:  https://www.google.com/search?q=rsync+for+windows

Comment: The question had already been edited to provide a solution (one without rsync). In summary, replace the `.` with `$(pwd)`

Comment: @JanD Using $(pwd) doesn't work when you're trying to upload directories that are not the current working directory, which is why I provided the answer I did.  Take a look at the very first example in my answer, this is taken verbatim from a script which used the "." notation that scp no longer supports.