# Scp the current dir `.` to another name

Tags: scp

This is an edge use case, but I can't find a solution.

I want to copy the current directory `.`, without necessarily knowing or caring for its name, to a new directory. Using `scp`.

Bash does not seem to have a problem. e.g. `cp -r . ../new-name` will generate a new directory copy without any problems. But with `scp -r . host:new-name` i get `scp: error: unexpected filename: .`

The workarounds I'm using is to use `rsync` instead of `scp`, or to use `scp -r ../current-name` instead of `scp -r .`. But it would be nice to understand why the obvious way do not work with scp and if there's a simpler 'fix'.

Also note that I do no want to scp the contents of the current directory to another already-existing directory as in `scp -r ./* host:existing-dir/`. The goal is to copy the current directory itself to a new location (i.e. create a new directory)-

Answer (score 30):

According to [this previous answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1403473/scp-error-unexpected-filename), the culprit is [CVE-2017-20685](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2018-20685); apparently, malicious remote hosts could exploit improper name validation, so support for `.` in paths for scp was disabled. The workaround is to replace `.` with `$(pwd)`.

Comment: How about remote CWD? Is there a similar "trick" for that?

Comment: PS: You mean `"$(pwd)"`, right?  (I just had a failure because the Windows 10 version of scp trips on filenames that contain spaces)

Answer (score 12):

You can expand `.` to the full path using something like `${PWD}`, `pwd` or `readlink -f .`

```
scp -r "${PWD}" ${remote}:${dst_path}
```

Comment: That only works correctly if the destination does not yet exist. If the destination already exists you get a new directory named after the source directory inside the destination.

Answer (score 3):

`scp ./* demo@test.com:/targetdir`

I try `./*` replate `-r ./`, it work